# Can TableGateway Use Multiple Tables Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In my module.php file, I want to pass multiple table names via TableGateway class in Zend Framework but I cannot find any documentation on it, other than it being limited to one table. The phpdoc for this (TableGateway) class says an array can be passed but again, I am not sure if it accepts more than one table.

for example in Module.php:

```
 'Application\Model\LoginModel' => function($sm) {
     $table_gateway = $sm->get('LoginService');
     $table = new LoginModel($table_gateway);
     return $table;
 },

 'LoginService' => function($sm) {
     $db_adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
     $result_set_prototype = new ResultSet();
     $result_set_prototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Login());
     return new TableGateway(array('admins', 'members'), $db_adapter, null, $result_set_prototype);
 }
```

Is it possible to do this and have multiple tables referenced or bound like this, or is it only designed to allow one table for each instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Table Gateway object is intended to provide an object that represents a table in a database. `Array` can be passed to the constructor, but if you pass it, you will get `InvalidArgumentException`. Please check this code

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/release-2.8.2/src/TableGateway/TableGateway.php#L34,L35

Please look at again `TableGateway` purposed on documentation here

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html